# CSS обращение к классу элемента по класу самого же элемента (не знаю как правильнее задать вопрос)

Tags: html, css

Есть ссылка

```html
<a class="btn tiny"></a>
```

Нужно задать стили для .tiny который обязательно привязан именно к .btn

если просто использовать

```css
.tiny {
  /*Стили*/
}
```

То если будут ещё элементы например

```html
<a class="link tiny"></a>
```

То стили применятся и к ним тоже.

Не знаю возможно ли такое, но буду благодарен за ответ.

Comment: `.btn.tiny { ...` только для `.btn` и только с `.tiny` , а если еще и только для ссылки, то `a.btn.tiny { ... {` чтобы уже наверняка

Comment: @HamSter а разве это не одно и тоже с конструкцией .btn .tiby {...}?

Comment: `.btn .tiby {...} ` Вы тут написали `tiby ` думаю просто ошиблись. И поставили пробел между классами. Если есть пробел между классами, то это означает что Вы задаете стили для элемента `.tiny` расположенного внутри блока `.btn`

Comment: `.btn.tiny { .... ` это для `<a class="btn tiny"> .... </a>`, а `.btn .tiny { .... ` это для `<a class="btn"> <span class="tiny"> ... </span> </a>`

Comment: @HamSter спасибо, всё понял. Я раньше просто думал что пробел между ними не важен и это одно и тоже.

Comment: https://webref.ru/css#selectors

Answer (score 0):

В CSS можно как можно более точнее указывать, к какому элементу нужно обращаться.
В вашем случае, можно использовать связку классов, выглядеть это будет так: `.btn.tiny {...}`.

Пример:

```css
.tiny {
  /* Уберёт подчёркивание у всех ссылок с классом .tiny */
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Но элементу с классом btn tiny мы хотим добавить подчёркивание */
.btn.tiny {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn tiny">btn tiny</a> | <a class="link tiny">link tiny</a>
```

---

Можно даже использовать [атрибуты](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), но это уже другая история.